# keySet() or propertyNames(). Is using propertyName() ok?

Tags: java, data-structures, properties, keyset

I am working with a `java.util.Properties` object, and I generally use `keySet()` to get all the keys of the properties.

I was wondering which is better `keySet()` or `propertyNames()`.

`propertyNames()` returns the enumeration of the keys - is it because of that I generally see `keySet` being used? Or is it ok to use `propertyNames()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the sourcecode it seems, that propertyNames() considers the "defaults" where as keySet() wouldnt do that (since it is not overloaded).
The defaults are a second Properties object which can optionally be passed to the constructor.
So if you dont use that "defaults" argument in the constructor, keySet() is more efficient (if this matters for you), but generally more correct will be propertyNames().

Comment: thanks @thomas-philipp...this clarified. So, if defaults are to be fetched  - we generally go for propertyNames() and keySet() for the assigned properties. While validating - I came across this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). Thanks.